# Voronoi cells algorithm can return the same value twice?

Tags: java, algorithm, voronoi, procedural-generation

Can voronoi algorithm can return the exact same value for two differents cells even very far away from each other ?
I don't think that depends on the implementation but [here](https://github.com/TJHJava/libnoiseforjava/blob/master/src/libnoiseforjava/module/Voronoi.java) is the code I use.

Comment: It take three coordinate (x,y,z) a return a double, the same value can return from close coordinates, that from cells (regions)

Comment: Voronoi isn't always used for noise - but I can't see why that algorithm couldn't generate the same value for multiple cells.